# Is the mysql connector needed when I am trying to connect using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been fetching data from database to my JAVA program by using JDBC till now and I am doing so by creating a connection class and in that class I will use the DriverManager.getConnection() fnc, but as I am moving towards JPA I have learnt that a persistence.xml file is needed to connect to mysql. In the project where I am using JPA am i supposed to create this connection class again and should I place the connector jar file in the project where I will be using jpa.

Excuse my unawarness of the concept I am still in the learning phase.Any help is appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: Both `JDBC` and `JPA` need to have `MySQL` connector (Driver) on the classpath.

Comment: Got that.But am I supposed to create a connection using Driver manager.get Connection() if I am using persistence.xml

Comment: You're not. You're supposed to use the `EntityManagerFactory` to get an `EntityManager`.

Comment: @Boristhespider Thanks that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Need to clear for you.

1. JPA is a specification. Different ORM technology uses it. Like hibernate implemented JPA specification. Specification defines how it works.
2. Hibernate is ORM technology. It binds Your Plain Java Object (Entity) to your database tables. And table's column will be Entity's field. Like Table has Id column of number type, in entity it will be **Long id;** . table name will be entity name or others that is defined in hibernate docs.
3. 3rd One is Database connector. Yes there is different types of connector for every database. like for mysql connector is using to connect your implemented code  with databases. You can think Its a communication Layer for database and your code. Your code is communicating with database through this connector.

Hope now you get concept why mysql connector is needed to connect. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Understood. So mysql connector is needed as it is the link between my Java code and database. But do I have to create a connection using Driver manager.getconnection if I am using persistence.xml

Comment: Yes you are right. Persistence.xml use for configuration jpa. But its works through connector library

Comment: @Sarthak Hibernate will create the connections for you.

Comment: @chrylis so need to write .get connection fnc to establish connection?

Comment: @Sarthak Your question is not understandable.

Comment: my sincere apologies, I have got the answer for my query.What I was trying to say was, after I have configured the connection in persistence.xml,Am i supposed to call the function DriverManager.getconnection function? and answer is no. persistence.xml will take care of it. Thank you for help!